# D Programming: openssl rsa forward reference compiler error

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-errors, openssl, rsa, d

```
import std.stdio;
import deimos.openssl.bn;
import deimos.openssl.rsa;

const KEY_SIZE = 1024;

void main(string[] args) {
    if (args.length < 1) {
        writeln("too few arguments");
    }

    RSA* rsa = RSA_new();
    rsa = RSA_generate_key(KEY_SIZE, RSA_F4, null, null);
    if(rsa==null) {
        writeln("failure");
    }
    else {
        writeln("success");

        // error generated by the line below
        if(!BN_generate_prime(rsa.p, (KEY_SIZE/2), 1, null, null, null, null)) {
            writeln("prime_failure");
        }
        else {
            writeln("prime success");
        }

        RSA_free(rsa);
    }   
}
```

This leads to the following error:

```
rsa.d(21): Error: struct rsa_st is forward referenced
```

The error occurs anytime I try to access an element in the rsa struct. Any ideas?

Comment: What command are you using to compile your program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get in contact with one of the people who frequently updates the OpenSSL Deimos on github and was able to get a response from him.

Basically the OpenSSL C API forward-declares structs in some places where the exact definitions are not required and these have stuck around in some of the D modules.

He requested a pull to the repository and the changes he made will fix your current problem. Here is the link:

[Deimos: openssl update](https://github.com/D-Programming-Deimos/openssl/pull/4)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the OpenSSL bindings are done, or tested. They're completely broken on `dmd 2.057` over here. The initial issue is a `dmd` bug; moving `import deimos.openssl.rsa` before the other `openssl` `import` should *change* the error to something else. Which can be resolved by importing pkcs7 in the affected module…which unearths *another* error.

I would open an issue on the openssl deimos project.